# Missing fields in the Edit Item View

Tags: sharepoint, view, edit

I have stumbled across another problem after doing a successful migration.   On one of the list, there are some missing fields when you go to edit an item.   these same fields show up when you go to view an item.   I do not recall hiding any fields and with with only two of 25 fields not showing is puzzling.   Any ideas in the programming world as to what may have taken place?

Answer (score 1):

Are you migrating code from 2007 to 2010? If so, you should look at these views in SharePoint Designer.  You should have the ability to create a new View (with the desired fields), make it default and omit the older view.

Answer (score 0):

I am *guessing* that the 2010 upgrade is a red herring and in fact whaat has happened is that

- You've modified the edit form using SharePoint Designer (SPD) thereby 'fixing' the fields to those in place at that time.
- You've later added some extra fields.
- These will appear on the View as that wasn't edited and 'fixed' but not edit.